# Thee element type 'Color?' can't be assigned to the list type 'Color'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

get this errors The element type 'Color?' can't be assigned to the list type 'Color' on the darkBackground.evaluate(ba)

```dart
 double _w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double _h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: ba,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            width: _w,
            height: _h,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: aT.evaluate(ba),
                end: aB.evaluate(ba),
                colors: [
                  darkBackground.evaluate(ba),
                  
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

and the darkBackground is

```
Animatable<Color> normalBackground = TweenSequence<Color>(
    [
      TweenSequenceItem(
        weight: .5,
        tween: ColorTween(
          begin: smalt.withOpacity(.6),
          end: oldRose.withOpacity(.6),
        ),
      ),
      TweenSequenceItem(
        weight: .5,
        tween: ColorTween(
          begin: oldRose.withOpacity(.6),
          end: smalt.withOpacity(.6),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
```

i tried to do this  but nothing change

```
Animatable<Color?> lightBackground = TweenSequence<Color?>(`
```

Comment: you are using darkbackground, showing us normalbackground and changing lightbackground?